# VB.net autocomplete textbox textchanged for 3 characters min

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

For a Windows desktop VB.NET application, I am trying to invoke auto suggest only when user type 3 letters or more. The database contains thousands of rows and I do not want to load all of them on form load. I want to only get from database when needed and for items matching first few letters.

So far I have

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) >= 3 Then
        'invoke autosuggest
    End If
End Sub
```

Then not sure how to invoke autosuggest so that user would not have to type the full text, my query would be something like:

```sql
Select Fullname, email from Contact where fullname like & textbox1.text order by full name
```

Any direction or code suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Query the database for a list of strings that begin with `TextBox1.Text`. Set this list as the `TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query as  :

```
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim con As SqlConnection ='your connexion string here

        Dim csql As String = "Select Fullname, email from Contact where fullname like @SEARCH  order by full name"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(csql, con)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEARCH", "'" + TextBox1.Test + "%'")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

an dalso use

```
 If TextBox1.Text.Length >3 Then
        'invoke autosuggest
    End If
```

instead of

```
  If Len(TextBox1.Text) >= 3 Then
        'invoke autosuggest
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I link the data to the textbox?

Comment: You can use autocomplete for your textbox have a look at this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx   .and please if the answer is helful for you mark it and vote it up

Comment: _**SQL Injection vulnerability!**_

Comment: @VisualVincent not my answer by any means, but do you minding showing the `SQL Injection vulnerability` you mention?

Comment: @zaggler : Well I don't know much about SQL, but this looks like a vulnerability to me: `'" & textbox1.text & "%'`.

Comment: @zaggler : (again I don't know much about SQL) But what if something like this was entered in TextBox1 (assuming the name exists): `Andersen%'; DROP TABLE <blabla>--`?

Comment: Good assumptions, but the drop would never happen as it would be included in the `like` syntax... Also the query is followed by an `OrderBy` which is invalid even if the drop statement would be able to run...

Comment: @zaggler : But the `OrderBy` part isn't forced as far as I know. Notice the comment on the end (`--`). Also, wouldn't the `';` part close the `LIKE` statement?

Comment: Practice save querying and use parameters for constructing your query

Comment: @Bill Anderson I have change my answer use request with parameters that's beter way to avoid the injection vulnerability